# Tomcat and MYSQL porting to AWS

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, tomcat

I have a working java 7 app that runs on tomcat 7 and MYSQL. I am trying to get it running on the basic (free tier) platform offered by Amazon AWS. I have succesfully loaded data to the RDS instance of MYSQL Community and set up an Elastic Beanstalk instance where basic JSPs are running correctly.

I am new to AWS so main problem should be my lack of knowledge.

I am not able to connect to the database from my code.

This is the code I am using to create the connection pool:

```
package com.authz.pap;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class DBConnections {
    private static DataSource dataSource;

    private static final DBConnections instance = new DBConnections();

    static
    {
        try
        {
            Context c = new InitialContext();
            dataSource = (DataSource)c.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/authzDB");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            dataSource = null;
        }
    }
    private DBConnections()
    {
    }

    public static DBConnections getInstance()
    {
        return instance;
    }

    public static DataSource getGeoServDS() {
        //if(dataSource==null) instance = new DBConnections();
        return dataSource;
    }

}
```

And this:

```
public DbCon() {

    conn=null;
    ProcessStatus stat = new ProcessStatus();
    stat.function="DbCon.DbCon";
    stat.message = "Initializing DB";
    stat.retcode=0;
    stat.record();
    try {
        conn=DBConnections.getGeoServDS().getConnection();
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        stat.message = e.toString();
        stat.retcode=-1;
        stat.record();
    }
}
```

And this is the content of the context.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/rest">
  <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" maxActive="8" maxIdle="4" name="jdbc/authzDB" password="xxxx" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:mysql://x.x.x.x:3306/authzDB?autoReconnect=true&amp;allowMultiQueries=true" username="root"/>
  <ResourceLink global="jdbc/authzDB" name="jdbc/authzDB" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
</Context>
```

What I get is a `java.lang.NullPointerException` on DB initialization.

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

This is the content of the web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>paprest</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>PAP rest interface</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.authz.pap.intfc</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest interface</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Do you have resource-ref in your web.xml file?

Comment: No. What should I put on it?

Comment: After Servlet mapping you need to add below configuration      
 <resource-ref>
      <description>DB Connection</description>
      <res-ref-name>jdbc/authzDB</res-ref-name>
      <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
      <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>

Comment: Still the same java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double response:

1- I have not been able to use the data from context.xml file. I have ised a different solution:

```
private static Connection getRemoteConnection() {
    ProcessStatus stat = new ProcessStatus();
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String dbName = "xxxxDB";
        String userName = "xxxxx";
        String password = "xxxxxx";
        String hostname = "xxxxxxxx";
        String port = "3306";
        String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://" + hostname + ":" + port + "/" + dbName + "?user=" + userName + "&password=" + password + "&autoReconnect=true&amp;allowMultiQueries=true";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl);
        return con;
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { stat.error(e.toString());}
    catch (SQLException e) { stat.error(e.toString());}
    return null;
  }
```

2- I had a different problem, as the RDS instance is not to be created independently but related to the Elastic Beanstalk. This allows the comunication betwen tomcat and Mysql.